# Spring JPA generating infinite Query

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jackson

I have the following entities:

User:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name="user_account")
public class User extends AbstractAuditableEntity implements UserDetails {
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = NOT_AUDITED)
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    private Currency preferredCurrency;
```

Currency:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Audited
public class Currency extends AbstractAuditableEntity {
    private String isoCode;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal euroConversion;
    private String symbol;
}
```

ExpenseType:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Audited
public class ExpenseType extends AbstractAuditableEntity {
    private String name;
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    private ExpenseType parentExpenseType;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentExpenseType", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ExpenseType> childExpenseTypes;
}
```

And finally, Expense:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Expense extends AbstractAuditableEntity {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private LocalDateTime expenseDate;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private boolean isIncome;

    @ManyToOne
    private Currency currency;

    @ManyToOne
    private ExpenseType expenseType;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
}
```

And their parent class AbstractAuditableEntity is the following one:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Getter
@Setter
@Audited
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"createdBy", "lastModifiedBy", "createdDate", "lastModifiedDate" })
public abstract class AbstractAuditableEntity extends AbstractPersistable<Long> implements Serializable {
    @JsonIgnore
    @Version
    protected Integer version;

    @CreatedDate
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_date", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    protected LocalDateTime createdDate;
    @LastModifiedDate
    @JoinColumn(name = "last_modified_date")
    protected LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

    @CreatedBy
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    protected User createdBy;
    @LastModifiedBy
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "last_modified_by_id")
    protected User lastModifiedBy;
}
```

When I try to do
`repository.findById(id)`
to get a "Expense" entity, I am getting the following error:
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: JDBC exception executing SQL

[select e1_0.id,e1_0.amount,c1_0.id,c2_0.id,c2_0.created_by_id,c2_0.created_date,c2_0.email,c2_0.enabled,l1_0.id,l1_0.created_by_id,l1_0.created_date,l1_0.email,l1_0.enabled,l1_0.last_modified_by_id,l1_0.last_modified_date,l1_0.name,l1_0.password,p1_0.id,c3_0.id,c3_0.created_by_id,c3_0.created_date,c3_0.email,c3_0.enabled,c3_0.last_modified_by_id,c3_0.last_modified_date,c3_0.name,c3_0.password,c3_0.preferred_currency_id,c3_0.version,p1_0.created_date,p1_0.euro_conversion,p1_0.iso_code,l2_0.id,l2_0.created_by_id,l2_0.created_date,l2_0.email,l2_0.enabled,l2_0.last_modified_by_id... **and so on**

What entity could cause this issue? I can't find the error.

I tried to put some Entities to Lazy Loading but to be honest I really need them to be loaded.

User has a Currency but Currency has not an User out of "createdBy" and "lastModifiedBy".
Expense has one of each: User, Currency and ExpenseType.
ExpenseType can have a parent, and I need it to load all their parents back.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when executed outside of testing environment, so it was just a "@Transactional" annotation of the test class.